# Display.asyncExec vs Display.timerExec

Tags: swt

I was hoping that `Display.timerExec(int,Runnable)` was much the same as `Display.asyncExec(Runnable)` but with the specified delay. However it appears that `Display.timerExec` can *only* be executed on the GUI thread, as its 1st line is a call to `checkDevice()`. This throws an exception if you're not running in a GUI thread.

Can anyone suggest a means to using `Display.asyncExec()` but with a delay preceding execution?

Comment: `timerExec()` is currently considered as the mother of bugs on the eclipse mailinglist. So one should be prepared that it is going to be removed in due time and hence abstain using it.

Answer (score 6):

You can first switch to the GUI thread with `asyncExec`, then schedule a timer action with `timerExec`. These two methods are similar in that they both execute some action, but `asyncExec` only switches thread, `timeExec` only schedules an action for the GUI thread.

```java
display.asyncExec(() -> display.timerExec(100, () -> doThings()));
```

This uses lambda expressions, which where introduced in Java 8.

With Java 7 or earlier one has to write it with anonymous classes like this:

```java
display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        display.timerExec(100, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doThings();
            }
        });
    }
});
```